# Obtain access rights, file names and it's sizes from ls command

Tags: bash

i need to get data listed in title from ls command, for example i want format:

- -rw-r--r-- 1 zivero zivero   17 Jan 11 18:16 example to:
- -rw-r--r-- 17 example

I tried `ls -lah | cut -d " " -f 1, 5,9` but due to files sizes delimiter before file size is sometimes one space sometimes more than that so it's working not for all files in folder.

Comment: I recommend this to be considered: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Have a look at `stat(1)`, esp. its `--printf` or `--format` arguments.

Comment: Gnu findutils's has a print format for permissions `find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%M\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```sh
stat --format='%A %s %n' example
```

Sample output:

```sh
$ stat --format='%A %s %n' example
-rw-r--r-- 17 example
```

If you what to perform this on a different file, replace `example` with the path to that file.

You can also perform this on multiple files at once. For example:

```sh
$ stat --format='%A %s %n' ./*
-rw-r--r-- 17 ./example
-rw-r--r-- 0 ./foo
```

From the [`stat` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html), we know that `--format` can be used to format output of `stat`.

I used the following format sequences:

- `%A`: display permission bits and file type in human readable form
- `%s`: display total size, in bytes
- `%n`: display file name